# ImportError: cannot import name 'TfidVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I run into this error in google colabs running cells.

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import json
import pickle

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidVectorizer

ImportError: cannot import name 'TfidVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py)

Answer (score 0):

You have it misspelled. Try `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer`